# Trouble Loading Assets Through Nginx Ingress for SonarQube Deployment on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, sonarqube, kubernetes-ingress

I am currently facing an issue with serving assets for my SonarQube deployment on a Kubernetes cluster using the Nginx Ingress Controller. When accessing the SonarQube UI through the browser, the assets (CSS, JS files) are not loading properly, and I receive the following error in the browser console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://internal.domain.com/js/outDLYDOPRS.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Here’s a brief overview of my setup:

- SonarQube is deployed as a service named sonarqube-sonarqube running on port 9000 in my Kubernetes cluster.
- I have set up an Nginx Ingress resource to route traffic to the sonarqube-sonarqube service.
- The Ingress resource is configured with rules to route traffic for different paths to the sonarqube-sonarqube service.

```
# MY INGRESS FILE 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-ingress
  namespace: sonarqube
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: internal.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: sonarqube-sonarqube
                port:
                  number: 9000
```

Despite these configurations, the assets are not loading as expected. I have verified the service’s status, checked the Ingress Controller logs, and reviewed the Ingress resource status, but I couldn’t identify the issue.

Other Details

- Helm Version v3.12.3
- Kubectl Version v1.27
- Sonarqube Helm Chat version sonarqube-8.0.2+754
- Sonarqube App Version 9.9.2

Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this asset loading issue? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Here’s what’s currently happening:

When a call is made to https://internal.domain.com/, the index file is successfully returned. However, this index file makes a call to a script using a relative path. For instance, when a request is made to https://internal.domain.com/js/file.js, I encounter a MIME type error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the CSS and JS file access are returning a 404 html page. You can confirm this by directly accessing css path in your browser.

My recommendation is to not use rewrite annotation option until needed as this might be rewriting the path of js and CSS back to root "/"

Try this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-ingress
  namespace: sonarqube
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: internal.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: sonarqube-sonarqube
                port:
                  number: 9000
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I've attempted the suggested solutions, but no luck. In my scenario, I need the routing to function in the following manner: a request to https://internal.domain.com/aa/bb should be routed to http://service:port/aa/bb

Comment: Did you check the response of the url for css directly in the browser. What is the response?

Comment: yeah, When I tried the css url in browser directly, it give me the index.html file

Comment: Please let me know your deployment environment, is it on prem or on cloud. If cloud please mention the cloud provider.

Comment: we are using AWS cloud.

Comment: @Joish  Ok, looks like this is behaving differntly in AWS. I would like you to try a few things.  You can go back to your original ingress definition you have shared in your question. First, in the rules section change the path to path: /(.*)  Next change the rewrite-target: annotation to /$1  Let me know your observation after these changes